# Type 'NSArray?.Type' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Tags: swift

I am facing issue in Swift after converting from Objective-C. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
var panels = NSArray?

func buttonTotalWidth() -> CGFloat {
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        for panel: UIView? in panels {
            width += panel?.frame.width
        }
        return width
    }
```

My Objective C code

```
@property NSArray *panels;

- (CGFloat)buttonTotalWidth {
    CGFloat width = 0;
    for (UIView *panel in self.panels) {
        width += CGRectGetWidth(panel.frame);
    }
    return width;
}
```

[image: Error Screen]

Comment: `NSArray?.self` doesn't create an array.  If you want an array of `[UIView?]` then you would do `var panels = [UIView?]()`

Comment: @dan Look it my objective C code

Comment: What does the code that assigns the value to the `panels` property look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't try to translate ObjC code literally to Swift. Learn the Swift specific stuff.

A *swifty* translation could be

```
var panels = [UIView]()

func buttonTotalWidth() -> CGFloat {
    return panels.map{$0.frame.width}.reduce(0.0, + )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method accepts the array of UIView(and not optional UIVIew), try this

```
var panels = self.view.subviews
var width = buttonTotalWidth(panels)

func buttonTotalWidth(_ panels: [UIView]) -> CGFloat {
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    for panel: UIView in panels.enumerated() {
        width += panel.frame.width
    }
    return width
}
```

if those are some optional UIViews, try this,

```
func buttonTotalWidth(_ panels: [UIView?]) -> CGFloat {
    var width: CGFloat = 0
    for panel: UIView? in panels.enumerated() {
        width += panel?.frame.width
    }
    return width
}
```